# "ConnectionString has not been initialized" error when calling two different repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `ASP.NET 5` / `ASP.NET Core` with `EF7` / `EF Core`

I have the following repository class that uses ASP.NET 5's dependency injection

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class PersonRepository :IPersonRepository
    {
        private MyDbContext _db;

        public MyRepository(MyDbContext db) 
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> Search()
        {
            var table = from p in _db.Persons
                        select p;

            return await table.ToListAsync();
        }            
    }
    public interface IPersonRepository
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<Person>> Search();
    }
}
```

Calling from my ASP.NET MVC controller I can call search successfully and get the data.

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private IPersonRepository _personRepository;

    public PersonController (IPersonRepository personRepository){
        _personRepository= personRepository;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> PersonAction()
    {
        var result = await _personRepository.Search();
    }
}
```

However something odd happens when I call another repository method call of a stored proc in another repository before this working repository  call.

Stored proc

```
public async Task<List<sp_GetList_Result>> sp_GetList()        
{  
    const string query = "exec [dbo].[sp_GetList];";
    var list = new List<sp_GetList_Result>();

    using (var connection = (SqlConnection)_db.Database.GetDbConnection())
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {         
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var row = new sp_GetList_Result();
                    //populate row

                    list.Add(row);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();               
        }
    }
    return list;   
}
```

Action Method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PersonAction()
{
    var list = await _anotherRepository.GetList();
    var result = await _personRepository.Search();
}
```

Suddenly  `await _personRepository.Search();` throws an exception

> InnerException = {"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."}

I explicitly comment out `connection.Close();` line but it still gives me the same connectionstring property has not been initialized error message.

Comment: This really ought to have been given a better error message by now!

Answer (score 19):

The problem does not lie with calling `connection.Close()`, but rather with the `connection.Dispose()` call, which is called when exiting the `using` block. In my case, replacing 
`using (var connection = (SqlConnection)_db.Database.GetDbConnection())` with

```
var connection = (SqlConnection)_db.Database.GetDbConnection();
try {
  // db stuff
}
finally {
  connection.Close();
}
```

worked fine, but I am still to understand what actually happens. Looks like the dispose creates an incosistent state for Database object internals that are used for getting the DbConnection.

Comment: ran into the same issue and i can't also explain it.

Comment: I'm using EF Core 3.1 and a using block still breaks it when there are multiple database calls on a request (first one works; 2nd one fails with missing connection string).  I find myself dropping down to ado.net a lot in core because EF core does not support filling a list of primitives from a database call (like the Framework Database.SqlQuery() allows). I think I might instead create object wrappers around my primitives and create a DbSet, seems like it would be less work and less danger of accidentally leaving a memory leak.

Comment: @TomRegan, personally I been happily using SqlKata with Dapper for non EF Registered Entity objects. Created some methods/extension methods on top og my Db Context to help with the boilerplate :)

Answer (score 4):

In my code above I changed

```
using (var connection = (SqlConnection)_db.Database.GetDbConnection())
```

to

```
var connection = (SqlConnection)_db.Database.GetDbConnection();
```

and then I don't close the connection which the using end bracket would do.

Comment: you are my hero of the day!